# Cutting a texture in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, textures

I use libgdx and I have a problem :(

I have a box and I wanna apply a part of a texture, not the entire texture. I'm unable to find a way to cut a portion of my texture. The cutting part of the texture it is a rectangle which starts at (x, y) and it have a width and a height. It's like TextureRegion, but i didn't find a way to applay the textureRegion to a model. 
Can anyone tell me how to cut the texture?

Any answer or suggestion is more than welcome.

Gratefully,
Abi

Comment: Is this a 3D model that you imported? If so, you either need to change your source model to be textured with a certain region of the model, or you can write a shader that modifies texture coordinates to pull from a region of the texture. Can you describe in more detail why you need a certain part of the texture on your model and if the region has to change or be decided at runtime?

Answer (score 5):

I think I resolved this :D

I use the pixmap.

```
Pixmap bigTexture = new Pixmap(Gdx.files.getFileHandle("bigTexture.png", FileType.Internal));

int w = ...;
int h = ...;
int srcX = ...;
int srcY = ...;

Pixmap partTexture = new Pixmap(w, h, Format.RGBA8888);
partTexture.drawPixmap(bigTexture, 0, 0, srcX, srcY, w, h);

Texture tx = new Texture(partTexture, Format.RGBA8888, false);
```